# Subtraction of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic

I was working on a problem booklet and came across the following equation.
$$\sqrt2\sin(2x)-\cos(2x)=\sqrt3\sin(2x-a)$$

$a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a specific value that I'm supposed to find, but I don't see how to make the first part look like the second part in the first place, so I can't even get there

Comment: What is $a$? Looks like this equation isn't true generally, but you can probably solve for some value of $a$ so that the equation holds.

Comment: a is a specific value that I'm supposed to find, but I don't see how to make the first part look like the second part in the first place, so I can't even get there.

Comment: To find the suitable $a$, you will be probably looking at the right-hand side and using  the identity $\sin(s-t)=\sin s\cos t-\cos s\sin t$.

Comment: Where does the $\sqrt{3}$ come from though?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to write
$$
\sqrt2\sin(2x)-\cos(2x)=A\sin2x\cos a-A\cos2x\sin a
$$
with $A>0$, because the addition formula says the expression is
$$
A\sin2x\cos a-A\cos2x\sin a=A\sin(2x-a).
$$
We can choose
$$
A\cos a=\sqrt{2},\quad A\sin a=1
$$
that gives
$$
A^2=A^2\cos^2a+A^2\sin^2a=2+1=3.
$$
Therefore $A=\sqrt{3}$ and so
$$
\cos a=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}},\quad
\sin a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.
$$
Since both sine and cosine are positive, you know that you can take $0<a<\pi/2$, thus
$$
a=\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.
$$